# Multiple JOINs returning only the last referenced table

Tags: postgresql, join, php

I've columns in different tables referenced in a one table, I'm running a query to fetch the fields related to those columns in their respective tables, but the query is returning only the last join (certstype.name from certifications.certid = certstype.id in this case) How do I modify the query to return names from all the tables I referenced. To make the question clear, I've also attached the relationship diagram.

**Environment**: PostGRESQL and PHP.

[image]

```
    $query = "SELECT certifications.*, users.name, company.name, certstype.name
                    FROM certifications
                    INNER JOIN users
                    ON certifications.candidate=users.id
                    JOIN company
                    ON certifications.company=company.id
                    JOIN certstype
                    ON certifications.certid=certstype.id
            WHERE certifications.candidate = 2
            ORDER BY 5 ASC";
```

Comment: The question is still unclear. Please include some sample data, the results you get from your query, and the results you expect. Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: php may not let you have multiple columns with the same name, in this case "name'.  Other languages have that problem with some dirvers/modes/functions, but not with other drivers/modes/functions.  You should assign aliases so that each column has a unique name.

Comment: @mustaccio I have the sample data, can I attach a CSV file or link it?

Comment: @jjanes Thank you for the direction. I've never used aliases before, can you show how my query will look like with the aliases?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I would advise you to use the same identifier throughout the model. Example: users.user_id, certifications.user_id. Besides being much more intuitive, you can also shorten your query a bit via the USING predicate: `users JOIN certifications USING (user_id) ...`

Comment: @Lennart You're right. I used different identifiers just while drawing up the chart. I never used "USING" before, will check it out. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a method to return data which needs unique column names, for example because it uses the column names as keys in a hash.  You can add aliases to make the column names unique.

This is the first line of your query with aliases:

```
SELECT certifications.*, users.name as user_name, company.name as company_name, certstype.name as cert_type_name
                    FROM ...
```

The "AS" keyword is optional between the name and the alias, but I think it makes things clearer.

If this doesn't fix things for you, you should show us the php code which is executing the query and fetching the data.

Comment: Thank you jjanes. Just following the suggestion from your comment, now it's working the way I expected using the aliases. I'm glad you submitted an answer as well as I can't mark comment as a solution.